# How can I use UTIs to get a list of video files in a directory that are playable by AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avplayer, uti

I've been trying to find out how to use UTIs (Unified Type Identifier) on macOS in swift, but have not been able to find anything. Does anyone know how I could use UTIs to get a list of video files in a directory that are playable by AVPlayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Hiroki Kato's UTIKit (https://github.com/cockscomb/UTIKit):

```
    let dir = URL(fileURLWithPath: "./your_dir_here")
    let mimeTypes = AVURLAsset.audiovisualMIMETypes()
    let playableUtis = mimeTypes.map { UTI(mimeType: $0)! }
    let dirContents = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: dir, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles])
    let movies = dirContents.filter { UTI("public.movie") ~= UTI(filenameExtension: $0.pathExtension) }
    let playableMovies = movies.filter {
        guard let movieUti = UTI(filenameExtension: $0.pathExtension) else {
            return false
        }

        return playableUtis.contains(movieUti)
    }
```

Now `playableMovies` contains only movie-files playable by `AVPlayer`.